# How do I generate these jQuery links inside of a <ul> element after the first <li> child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hi**, I'm having real trouble trying to solve this problem of mine. Although in my last 6-7 hours of despair I have come up with several viable options to make the problem go away, I haven't by any means been able to figure it out. I am trying to edit some source code (included) to achieve what the Title of this question suggests.

I am using the following jQuery plugin: [jQuery Cycle Plugin - Pager Demo with Prev/Next Controls](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html)

What I am trying to get this to do with my own markup is generate the links that contain the `<a>` elements within the `<li>` elements come after and before the first and last `<li>` elements contained in the targeted parent element...(`<ul>`). Here's the plugins configuration:

```
$(function() {

    $('.recent_slider').cycle({
        fx:      'scrollHorz',
        timeout:  0,
        prev:    '.slide_l',
        next:    '.slide_r',
        pager:   '.slide_nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
    });

    function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
        var s = idx > 4 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
        return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+idx+'</a></li>';

    };

});
```

Where `pager: '.slide_nav',` refers to the parent `<ul>` element, I have this plugin's next and previous controls being used as `<li><a href="" class="slide_l"></a></li>` (with slide_l meaning "slide left" / previous) and `<li><a href="" class="slide_r"></a></li>` (meaning "slide right" / next).

What I want to be able to do is insert the pager links generated from  `return <li'+s+'><a href="#">'+idx+'</a></li>` in between `.slide_l` and `.slide_r` so it appears something like:

```
<ul class="slide_nav">
    <li><a href="" class="slide_l"></a></li>
    <li'+s+'><a href="#">'+idx+'</a></li>
    <li'+s+'><a href="#">'+idx+'</a></li>
    <li'+s+'><a href="#">'+idx+'</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="slide_r"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The issue is that is adds them after so in effect I get something along the lines of `"previous","next", "slide1", "slide2", "slide 3"` where as what I need is `"previous","slide1", "slide2", "slide3", "next"`...

Here's the plugin's almighty 1500+ lines of [source code](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js) which together with the above configuration and markup containing the class names: `.slide_nav`, `.slide_l` and `slide_r`will cause the headache I'm having...

Please help.

Comment: So you are trying to add your LIs dynamically in between the two existing LI's?  Do you have any sample code of what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Correct...The closes thing I've done is nestest a <ul class="slide_nav"> into an <li> which is in a containing <ul>. However, I also need it to validate as W3C X(HTML) Transitional which it can't do if it's empty...I.e. if there's no hard coded <li></li> elements such as <li class="slide_l"> or <li class="slide_r"> then it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change how the UI is displayed, and not the structure of the content, CSS would be a better way to solve this.

Change your html to this:

```
<span class="slide_l"><a href="#">Prev</a></span>
<ul class="slide_nav"></ul>
<span class="slide_r"><a href="#">Next</a></span>
```

And add this CSS (note this is just a starting point, add onto it to make it look nice):

```
.slide_nav, .slide_nav li, .slide_l, .slide_r {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The CSS makes all the elements flow horizontally (using `display: inline-block`) to make it similar to a standard paginator.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwx1v9c7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the `html` of the `.slide_nav` and then mess with it as a string.

```
var x = $('.slide_nav').html();
var arr=x.split('</li>');
var mystr = '';
for (var r=0, len=arr.length; r<len; r++) {
  mystr += arr[r];
  if (r===0) {
    //your code to add additional LI's
  }
}
$('.slide_nav').html(mystr)
```

It's far from the most elegant solution but it should work.